# Firebird Prepared Statements

Tags: c#-4.0, firebird2.5

Can anyone advise if Firebird will cache query plans across sessions and, therefore, if FbCommand.Prepare() should be used or is useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebird keeps a query prepared until it is unprepared or the session is closed.
"Firebird does not keep a cache of prepared queries between connections" (from a message by Ann Harrison in [Re: [firebird-support] Firebird Prepared Queries](http://fb-list-archive.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/firebird-support/2010/2/106941.html))